# c# Input string was not in a correct format. Convert.ToDouble(variable)

Tags: c#, input

csv file : https://prnt.sc/p86gm9
actual code : https://prnt.sc/p86gxm

i tried puting .ToString() it didnt work. 
Any ideas why i get this error ?

Comment: I suppose your dot isn´t recognized as comma-sepaerator. Which culture are you in?

Comment: it shouldnt be seperated if i output an array of parts everything is correct but when try to assign it to class it show wrong format.  culture ?

Answer (score -1):

Somehow in your data, there is an empty value which isn't properly parsed, so you need to check those values first before parsing.

```cs
public static void Main()
        {
            string[] parts = { "6.50", "950" };
            double? weight = parts[0] != null && parts[0].Length > 0 ? double.Parse(parts[0]) : (double?)null;
            int? price = parts[1] != null && parts[1].Length > 0 ? int.Parse(parts[1]) : (int?)null;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It could be that you're trying to parse with the wrong culture.
For example, in German you write `3,5` instead of `3.5`.

```
double.Parse(valueString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

could help.
Maybe you also have leading or trailing spaces in the string, so you could also try `valueString.Trim()` while passing it into the `double.Parse` method.

If you want to parse the valueString with another culture info, you can specify this, too:

```
double.Parse("2,5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("fr-FR"))
```

Comment: On my french windows, I got 25 for 2,5

Comment: Now it works with commas instead of dots thank you !!

Comment: When you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, it should work too.

Comment: @OlivierRogier That's odd. `Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("2,5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("fr-FR")).ToString());` outputs `2.5`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("2,5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); => "25" but Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("2.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); => "2,5" [french windows]

Comment: That is the desired behavior. I think you don't understand what a `CultureInfo` is and what it does for parsing.

Comment: @pinki It works as long as one do not put commas in place of points.

Comment: Using GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag fr-FR on 2.5 cause an exception.

Comment: When you put commas, you have to specify another `CultureInfo`. With the french one, it would be correctly parsed.

Comment: Using `GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("fr-FR")` on `2.5` causes an exception, because it's the wrong number format for that culture. For `2.5` you have to set another `CultureInfo` like `InvariantCulture`. There is no solution that works for both correctly at the same time.

Comment: If numbers in the file are always with a point and this never change, InvariantCulture is ok just only because the DecimalSeparator is there a point.

Comment: In data exchange formats there is mostly a point. See JSON for example.